# Is there any placeholder notation in mta.yaml that removes spaces from the CF org name parameter?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

We are using mta to structure our application and deploying it using the SAP Cloud SDK Pipeline and Transport Management landscape.

In the mta.yaml, we are referencing the org (organization) parameter value using the placeholder notation ${org}.

The issue is that the org name contains spaces between the characters (viz. Sample Org Name) and that is causing error during the application deployment to Cloud Foundry.
We do not want to rename the org name.
Is there any other placeholder notation that removes the spaces between the characters?

We have observed that ${default-host} removes the spaces from the organization name but its scope is limited to only modules and not resources.
We need the substitution variable in the **resources** scope.

Appreciate if someone can help us here to resolve the issue.
Please find snippet of the mta.yaml and the error message.

```
resources:
  - name: uaa_test_app
    parameters:
      path: ./xs-security.json
      service-plan: application
      service: xsuaa
      config:
       xsappname: 'test-app-${org}-${space}'
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
```

**Error Message:**
Service operation failed: Controller operation failed: 502 Updating service "uaa_test_app" failed: Bad Gateway: Service broker error: Service broker xsuaa failed with: org.springframework.cloud.servicebroker.exception.ServiceBrokerException: Error updating application null (Error parsing xs-security.json data: Inconsistent xs-security.json: **Invalid xsappname "Test-App-Sample Org Name-test"**: May only include characters 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z', '0'-'9', '_', '-', '', and '/'.)

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
resources:
  - name: uaa_test_app
    parameters:
      path: ./xs-security.json
      service-plan: application
      service: xsuaa
      config:
       xsappname: 'test-app-${org}-${space}' #remove quotes
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**